# How to write "tsh" in Japanese?

Tags: grammar

"Tsh" sound like someone would say, I'm not sure what to call it, a snort maybe? Vegeta in Dragon Ball often makes this sound.

Answer (score 5):

チェッ、ちぇ、ちっ、チッ、ちぇっ. A form of 舌打ち{したうち｝ As in 「チッ、くだらん、なにがホグワーツ魔法学校だ！」
Weblio definition link [here](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%83%81%E3%83%83).

Answer (score -3):

Isn't it ちゅ? Sometimes like for ます、です う　is not pronounced. I hope I helped you :)
Maybe this onomatopoeias : ちゅっ
[image]